# Algorithm for realistic jump

Tags: xcode, physics

I want my character to jump according to how long the jump button is pressed. I've tried adding to the y position of the sprite when the jump buttons is held down..but it doesn't give a realistic feel to the jump. My increment is too constant. How do I make it so that the increment of y decreases when it reaches the top of its jump?

Comment: Jumping for a different amount of time depending on the amount of time that the jump button is pressed is never going to be realistic. In real life, all the upwards acceleration happens while the feet are touching the ground, and after that, there is just a constant downwards acceleration from gravity.

Comment: Well, he said he wants a realistic *feel*, which in games is something quite different from being truly realistic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a sine function to compute the height for a given time. It has roughly the shape that you want in order to give a "realistic" feel, and it's available as a library function in all kinds of language libraries.

Except this doesn't work if the player, say, jumps off a cliff, since the sine function starts to turn around and go the other direction once it drops below the starting elevation.

So, either you use a hybrid approach where you change up at that point, or you use more realistic physics, which is that downward acceleration begins the moment the player leaves the ground. In the latter case, you have to figure out what happens with holding down the button.

For playability, it might actually be advantageous to use the sine and then say that at the point in time when the player returns to the original elevation, acceleration stops and velocity remains constant from there on down.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways I think of for implementing this:

1. Imagine that your character has a jetpack with limited 'fuel'. Then, the acceleration is inversely proportional to the remaining fuel, so that he starts with high acceleration and slows down until the pack runs out of 'fuel' or the user releases the jump button. At that point acceleration should revert to gravity (negative), and the character starts falling. (With this story, at least, it makes sense for the user to continue rising as the jump button is held down).
2. Use a nonlinear function with a decreasing (but positive) slope to map the jump's duration to a y-value, e.g. a sine function, log function or square-root. This is a more general case of (1).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the jump button charging up the player character's "jump energy" (in the real world you could bend at the knees to jump higher, effectively driving more energy into the jump).

The energy at a certain height is determined by the formula `E = m g h`, where `m` is the mass of the thing moving, `g` a gravity constant and `h` the achieved height.
Note that the "launch" speed you need to acquire a certain jump is determined by the kinetic energy you have at that speed: `E = m v²/2`, resulting in `h = v²/(2g)` as a quadratic formula.

I therefore suggest trying a quadratic (bounded, you don't want people to jump to impossible heights) or a linear growth of the jump height `h` with time.